# macro to confirm data and copy and paste data

Tags: function, excel, worksheet-function, vba

I want to create a macro that will confirm that there is data in the following format  date, time or NA  in columns f,I,k,m and o, then copy my formula which is in row 16, columns s,t,u,v,x and y, for every row that has data in columns f,I,k,m and o. It's time-consuming to copy and paste manually all the rows.

In short, where there is data, copy my formula. The summary section and empty lines will be ignored. 
I have been playing with the copy and paste function, but can’t confirm/verify data in columns f,I,k,m and o.

- I have downloaded data from our DB to an Excel sheet.
- The data appears in columns f,I,k,m and o. The cells can contain dates, times and NA.
- Each row of data is separated by an empty row.
- At the end of each grouping, let’s say 25 to 50, the information is summarized, thus creating additional rows for the summary information, and then it repeats.

See data sample

```
3/25/13  5:33 PM    5:55:59 PM   5:57:49 PM     NA  NA  
3/25/13  6:12 PM    6:19:57 PM   6:23:16 PM     NA  NA  
3/25/13  5:15 PM    5:33:51 PM   5:46:39 PM     NA  NA  
3/25/13  5:19 PM    5:50:44 PM   6:08:51 PM     NA  NA
```

Summary section

```
    Avg Prep Time (in min): 21.63
    Avg Print to Delivery Time (in min):
            Avg Time Out (in min):  0.00
        # of Trays: 16
    Avg Prep Time (in min): 21.63
```

My formula in columns s,t,u,v,x and y

```
6:15 AM 6:33 AM 0:18    6:43 AM     0:28    29
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using these pieces of code

```
Sub GetFormat()
Range("A1").Value = Range("F1").NumberFormat
End Sub
```

Use it to find out what VBA calls the cell format. I think date is called "m/d/yyyy" and time is called "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
After finding out what your formats are called I suggest copy and pasting them into the following code (typing them manually didn;t work for me). For this example I have already put in the "m/d/yyyy"

```
Sub verify()
If Range("F1").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" Then
Range("F16").Copy Destination:=Range("A1")
End If
End Sub
```

Good Luck!

Comment: @user2254486, has this solved your question? Can we help more?